# Issue with controller generation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

New to Ruby on Rails so this may be a stupid question. I have an app and I can bundle my gems without issue.  So now I want to add some mostly static pages.  I try to generate a controller for them with rails generate controller MostlyStatic page1 page2.  This should generate a controller named mostly_static and pages named page1 and page2.  Instead, I throw an error.  Apparently the generate command is trying to connect to the database, which I have not yet created.  There is nothing in these pages that should be a database table, so I'm a bit confused as to why the database is being brought into the process at this juncture.  I've looked through various tutorials and none say that a database is required to generate controllers for static pages.  So... what am I missing?  Do I need to create the database first just to generate static pages?  And, if so, will subsequently dropping any tables created by that generation impair the function of my app?  I really don't want a bunch of useless tables for static pages hanging around.  Is there a way to generate these pages and controllers without the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this question, the correct answer is that the database need not exist, but it must be properly configured as if it did exist in the config file.  Generating the controller does not actually create the database.

Answer (score 3):

You are not following the convention for generating controllers. Generating a controller will not create a database table. You have to do that by calling `rails generate model`, `rails generate resource` or `rails generate scaffold`.

So you want a controller for a few static pages. Try this

```
rails generate controller static_pages home help contact
```

Notice the generator is plural and snake case (static_pages). this will generate the static controller and the `home.html.erb`, `help.html.erb`, and `contact.html.erb` pages

Now you can access the pages with these actions in the controller

```
def home
end

def help
end

def contact
end
```

Also need to make sure the routes are set up

```
# routes.rb

match '/home',    to: 'static_pages#home'
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/contact',    to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

No database is set up and you can visit the pages. Thats all you need to do. just follow the conventions,like plural controllers and singular models and rails takes care of the details. Hope this gets you started

UPDATE

in response to the comments here is the standard output of generating a controller. Note my example used haml instead of erb, but there is nothing related to the database in the output.

```
rails g controller static_pages home help contact
  create  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
   route  get "static_pages/contact"
   route  get "static_pages/help"
   route  get "static_pages/home"
  invoke  haml
  create    app/views/static_pages
  create    app/views/static_pages/home.html.haml
  create    app/views/static_pages/help.html.haml
  create    app/views/static_pages/contact.html.haml
  invoke  rspec
  create    spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb
  create    spec/views/static_pages
  create    spec/views/static_pages/home.html.haml_spec.rb
  create    spec/views/static_pages/help.html.haml_spec.rb
  create    spec/views/static_pages/contact.html.haml_spec.rb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/static_pages_helper.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/helpers/static_pages_helper_spec.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/static_pages.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss
```

Comment: While I do appreciate the attempt to help, most of what you have said here is not accurate.  You can use camel case or snake case to generate controllers, even though the generated controller will be snake case.  As for trying [code] rails generate controller static_pages home help contact [/code],that is essentially what I was trying in the first place.  After trying exactly that I still get the database error.  I can't find any reference stating as much, but there has to be some rule in the newer version of rails about databases before controllers.

Comment: As a reference for my point re: camel case vs snake case, please see section 3.4 of this Mike Hartl guide, which is supposed to be the best out there.  Though I will concede that in this guide, in this section in fact, he is saying to generate static page controller before the database which clearly is not working.  Anyway, here is the link.  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-static_pages

Comment: I actually used that tutorial as an example to show you how to generate static pages. The generating a controller has nothing to do with the database. The point of static pages is they are not persisting data from a database. They are static. They dont change. I think you are mixing up controllers and models. If you need a database table just generate a controller (plural) and a model (singular) with the same name. Or do it in one step with `rails generate scaffold`. There is nothing wrong with the information in my answer. Just offering my help and should not have been down voted.

Comment: Not to be difficult, but this is the exact result from running the command as you suggest:  

rails generate controller static_pages home help contact
/home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error).  Followed by roughly 30 lines of other database errors.  It is CLEARLY requiring the database to generate the controller, no?

Comment: No, whatever is happening with the database errors, I'm not sure about. See my updated answer. I have never seen that kind of error from generating a controller. It has to be something with your setup. you can use the rails destroy command to get rid of anything you generated previously. Also as a suggestion, stick to the default sqlite database when you are learning Rails. It will let you focus on learning Rails and not fight with the database when you are trying to learn. Just friendly advice. Post another question with the stack trace and exactly what you are doing so we can help